# str.split() return array and new line for every comma

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am working on the tokenizing the objects in ionic2, typescript/angular2.Here are the codes.

```
matchText(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var label = this.labels[i];

        var ingredients = label.description.toString().split([',', '(', ')', ' ']);

        let ingredientList: string[] = ingredients;

        console.log('list', ingredientList);

        for (var j = 0; j < ingredientList.length; j++) {
            console.log(ingredientList[j]);
            if (ingredientList[j] == 'SUGAR') {
                this.counter++;
                console.log('Match');
            }
            else {
                console.log('No Match');
            }
        }

        if (this.counter > 0) {
            //this.counter = 0;
            this.navCtrl.push(UnSafePage);
        }
        else {
            this.navCtrl.push(SafePage);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
INGREDIENTS
WHEAT FLOUR, SUGAR,
CHOCOLATE LIQUOR,
HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE
OIL(SAL FAT, SHEA BUTTER,
RAPESEED OIL, PALM OIL,
SUNFLOWER OIL), WHOLE MILK
POWDER, SHORTENING
(RAPESEED OIL, PALM OIL),
COCOA BUTTER, SALT, BUTTER,
YEAST, EMULSIFIER
(POLYGLYCEROLPOLYRICINOLEATE,
SOY LECITHIN), ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR,
TRISODIUMPHOSPHATE, LEAVENING
(SODIUM BICARBONATE)
CONTAINS: MILK, WHEAT,
SOYBEANS and SHEANUT.
Manufactured in a facility that uses
EGGS and PEANUTS.
```

How can i get this expected output?.Basically i want to leave a new line beside every ','.

```
INGREDIENTS
    WHEAT FLOUR, 
    SUGAR,
    CHOCOLATE LIQUOR,
    HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE
    OIL(SAL FAT, SHEA BUTTER,
    RAPESEED OIL, PALM OIL,
    SUNFLOWER OIL), 
    WHOLE MILK POWDER, 
    SHORTENING
    (RAPESEED OIL, PALM OIL),
    COCOA BUTTER, 
    SALT, 
    BUTTER,
    YEAST, 
    EMULSIFIER
    (POLYGLYCEROLPOLYRICINOLEATE,
    SOY LECITHIN), 
    ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR,
    TRISODIUMPHOSPHATE, 
    LEAVENING
    (SODIUM BICARBONATE)
    CONTAINS: MILK, 
    WHEAT,
    SOYBEANS and SHEANUT.
    Manufactured in a facility that uses
    EGGS and PEANUTS.
```

Comment: A replace function? `,` -> `'\n`?  And what happened to the comma between RAPESEED OIL and PALM OIL?

Comment: What i plan to do is i group them accordingly. Like those inside a bracket will be store in an element of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/buwabi/edit?js,console)

```
const mock = 'string , that , you, want, to, split'

const split = mock.split(',');

split.forEach(t => console.log(`${t} \n`))
```

Depending on your needs you may wish to prevent line breaks for commas that fall between parenthesis.

From Wikipedia.

### JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape character for

- \' single quote
- \" double quote
- \ backslash
- **\n new line**
- \r carriage return
- \t tab
- \b backspace
- \f form feed
- \v vertical tab (IE < 9 treats '\v' as 'v' instead of a vertical tab ('\x0B'). If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
- \0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it is an octal escape sequence)

**

Comment: Ok now it leave new line for every comma, now i am trying to figure out how to stick those in a bracket together and split accordingly